# the command name 'hg' cannot be found with 'executable find'

Tags: python, emacs, ropemacs

I am a new emacs user, and am trying to install ropemacs as I program in python mostly. So i used the command : `M-x el-get-install ropemacs`. But it gave me the following error:
"'`the command name 'hg' cannot be found with 'executable find`' "

I don't understand it at all and also suggest if there is some other plugin which can do the refactoring, etc I expect from ropemacs.

P.S. I'm running Emacs 24.3 on OS X 10.9

Comment: Did you install the python rope package? Also what is your os?

Comment: @user3114046: No. I believe ropemacs will take care of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) is missing in your system. It is a distributed version control system like Git or Bazaar. El-get tries to download ropemacs from its repository and it fails.

Or it can be installed, but is missing in your executable path. To detect where Mercurial is installed, type: `whereis hg` or `type -a hg`. Ordinary it is located in `/usr/bin/hg`. In other case, you have to add path to `PATH` variable. Open `~/.bashrc` on Linux, `~/.bash_profile` on OS X and append:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/hg/directory
```

More about changing PATH variable you can find [in this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/).

Comment: typing whereis hg returns nothing. I couldn't find hg in my /usr/bin folder either. But strangely typing hg on the terminal prompt runs it. How should I proceed?

Comment: what does `type -a hg` return? (I am not sure, if it works on OS X).

Comment: I found the hg file in /usr/local/bin/hg and put this path into my .bashrc file, but to no help! It still gives me the same error, this time on startup, and also when i try to install ropemacs.

Comment: Sorry, ``.bashrc`` is on Linux - edit ``.bash_profile`` instead. What exactly path do you add to the file? It should be ``/usr/local/bin``.

Comment: I've added "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" to my ~/.bash_profile file, but still no success.

Comment: I tried running emacs in my terminal and the process was completed successfully. Think emacs did not have access to my environment variables. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

This post might help:

http://edward.oconnor.cx/2008/02/ropemacs

download Pymacs, then python setup.py install

download rope, then python setup.py install

download ropemacs, then python setup.py install

Ensure pymacs.el is in your Emacs load-path.

Comment: not working. cannot find pymacs it says in a warning at startup.

Comment: I'm not really able to help anymore, I don't have a mac to experiment on.